# Fetch AWS CodeBuild environment variable [CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION] in AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-codebuild, sentry, aws-parameter-store

I need to obtain git commit sha from codebuild and use it in aws lambda environment variable. Is this possible? Thank you!